# Acceptable to include a definition list within a <figcaption> tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, swiper.js

### Background

I am using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) to create a slider for a restaurant website and I would like to code it as semantically as possible. To give you an idea of the content, each slide has four main features:

- Background image
- Menu category (i.e. sandwiches)
- Menu item
- Menu item description

If you need a visual (and an appetite):

[image: sandwich category slide]

### My Solution

This was the most semantic way I could think of to code it:

```
<figure class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="img/hammin-it-up.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
        <strong class="slider-menu-category">Sandwiches</strong>
        <dl class="slider-menu-item">
            <dt>Hammin' It Up</dt>
            <dd>Fontina Cheese & Blackforest Ham grilled on Texas Toast</dd>
        </dl>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

### My Question/s

1. Is it semantically friendly and w3-OK to use a `<dl>` within a `<figcaption>` tag?
2. Is there a more semantic way to show the slide "title" (aka category) than using a class? I realize this is a separate question, but it's related and I couldn't cram all that into the post title...

### My Research

I could not find a site with an exact match to what I did, but I found some that were close:

- MDN has some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) with a `<cite>` tag inside a `<figcaption>`.
- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) has an `<a>` and `<code>` inside the same.
- An S.O. user posted an indirectly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163294/html5-figure-figcaption-inside-a-paragraph-gives-unpredictable-output), but I noticed within their markup some `<p>` tags inside a `<figcaption>`.

[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element) indicates nothing suggesting my method was incorrect, so I am semi-sure it's fine, but any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is allowed inside of [`figure`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)/[`figcaption`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element): `dl` is flow content, and `figure`/`figcaption` expect flow content according to their [content model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346162/1591669).

However, I don’t think it’s the best choice in your specific example.

The `dl` doesn’t really *add* anything to understanding the content of this `figure`. It would be appropriate if there were several name-value pairs (e.g., "Price", "Ingredients" etc.), but what you currently have is just a title and a description.

The [`strong`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) element doesn’t seem to be used according to its definition ("strong importance, seriousness, or urgency") here.

And I also think that the category/title/description isn’t really a caption for the photograph in this case; to me, it seems these 4 elements should be on the same level, so to say. But this is open for interpretation and also depends on the context where this slideshow will be shown.

Instead of using `figure`, I think that each menu item should be an [`article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/sections.html#the-article-element). This choice enables the use of headings and `header` elements:

```html
<article>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <header>
    <div>Sandwiches</div>
    <h1>Hammin' It Up</h1>
  </header>
  <p>Fontina Cheese & Blackforest Ham grilled on Texas Toast</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Ah yes, article makes more sense. Any thoughts on using <h1> for the category and <h2> for the menu item? Those are the hierarchical priorities I would like to achieve.

Comment: @travelampel: I wouldn’t use a heading for the category (unless you have *several* menu items in scope of this same heading); the document outline would be confusing to read when there are several headings with the same category on the same level. If you don’t like the "[subheading](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/common-idioms.html#sub-head)" way I used, you could use *one* heading and include both, the category and the menu item (and style these parts differently), but I guess you should use singular instead of plural then: `<h1>Sandwich: <b>Hammin' It Up</b></h1>`

Answer (score -1):

use `<div> .. </div>` for everything , `<figcaption>` is allowed with HTML5

sticking with div's will be compatable with any browser on any device.  You can use a title attribute if you'd like.  You can also have any attribute as long as it starts with `data-`

and example would be `<div class="exampleClass" data-title="My Title" data-info="My other info">`